# Model Binder Not Finding Post Data

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core-webapi

I have a simple jquery post

```
function saveImage(base64) {
  $.post("http://localhost:50575/api/images", {base64Data: base64});
}
```

That is going against a .net core controller

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<ActionResult> Post(string base64Data)
{
    var base64 = Request.Form["base64Data"];
    return Ok();
}
```

When the data is posted, `base64Data` is null.  However, `base64`, which is populated from the form variables has a value.

Is there any reason why this shouldn't work?

Comment: What is the version for `Asp.Net Core project`? I fail to reproduce your issue with asp.net core 2.0 or asp.net core 2.1. Check how to reproduce your issue on [ModelBindingPro2_1](https://github.com/Edward-Zhou/AspNetCore/blob/2d99cb926b18a53067d8853d2b89b8913ae35cce/ModelBindingPro2_1/Controllers/JsonInputController.cs#L15)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What sent by `$.post("http://localhost:50575/api/images", {base64Data: base64})` is:

```
POST /api/images HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

base64Data=xxxxxxxx
```

Since you send the request with a content-type of **`application/x-www-form-urlencoded`** and have the request processed by a **`ApiController`** , you should decorate the parameter with a **`[FromForm]`**

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Post([FromForm] string base64Data)
{
    // ...
}
```

Or if you would like to send the request encoded with `application/json` , you should firstly create a `DTO` to hold the whole playload :

```
public class Base64Dto{
    public string Base64Data{get;set;}
}
```

and decorate the parameter with a `[FromBody]` at the same time :

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Post([FromBody] Base64Dto base64Data)
{
    // var base64 = Request.Form["base64Data"];
    return Ok();
}
```

Another way to hold the whole payload with `Base64Dto` , is to send the request with a header of `Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded` , and use a `[FromForm]` attribute at the same time :

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Post([FromForm] Base64Dto base64Data)
{
    // var base64 = Request.Form["base64Data"];
    return Ok();
}
```

Comment: Sorry for the really late response -- [FromForm] did the trick.